# use two different control-event on UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have created one dynamic button in my application and I call the following method:

```
[btnactions addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(deleteview:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];</b>
```

This `deleteview` method is used for delete the specific application view whenever I click the button.

Now, I want another method to call dynamically on button event

```
UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat
```

So how can I call two different events using different control events?

Comment: use this  `[btnactions addTarget:self action:@selector(methodName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call addTarget again with UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat

From the docs (UIButton inherits from [UIControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl)):

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

> You may call this method multiple times, and you may specify multiple
>   target-action pairs for a particular event. The action message may
>   optionally include the sender and the event as parameters, in that
>   order.